# have div stetch inside of div and fill up the empty div space

Tags: css, modal-dialog

I want to make a modal which will have a scrollable list of items. The scrollable element is the #content div. At the bottom of the modal I want to have footer which will be selected item from the scrollable div. What I cannot figure out for the life of me is to keep the scrollable div and the footer inside the modal div.

Right now I got the footer div outside the modal but how do I get the footer to be inside the modal element. When you inspect the elements you will see the footer is outside the modal and below the modal. I have tried using so many CSS tricks and I have had no luck.

```css
#background {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

#modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  bottom: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

#content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

#footer {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
  <div id="modal">
    <div id="content">
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
      <div>Selected Item</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

The best solution for legacy browsers is by replacing height in #content with...

```
#content {
    height: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

The best solution for IE11 and up is by adding the following CSS and removing the height from #content. Thanks to @Miro for these solutions.

```
#modal {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#content {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what exactly you want to do, can you please clearify which element should be scrollable?

Comment: The #content element should be scrollable.

Comment: you want the footer to  be always visible or when you scroll its a tthe bottom?

Comment: I would like the footer to always be visible.

Comment: the footer is already always visible on my end

Comment: Your are right it is visible but when you inspect the elements and have your mouse hover over the #modal div element the footer is not inside the element but outside and undernearth. I find this odd since the modal height is 50% but with the footer it is now over 50%.

Comment: if you want it inside you have to close the div content after the footer

Comment: but you did it, you just need to make it look more aesthetic

Comment: I did and I didn't. I do not want anything outside the modal. I want it to all be tucked inside the modal. The modal height is 50% of the window and I want it to stay that way and not be anymore then 50% in height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I inspect, the `#footer` does not appear to be outside the modal on my end. It's exactly where it's supposed to be as per the html. If you want the footer to be also scrollable then it needs to be inside the `#content`.

[image]

Edit: To make it work dynamically you can use [flex sticky footer](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/). Otherwise lookup 'css only sticky footer' for other solutions.

```css
#background {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

#modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  bottom: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
}

#footer {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
  <div id="modal">
    <div id="content">
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="footer">
        <div>Selected Item</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your are right it is visible but when you inspect the elements and have your mouse hover over the #modal div element the footer is not inside the element but outside and undernearth

Comment: I find this odd since the modal height is 50% but with the footer it is now over 50%.

Comment: That's because you set the height of the #content to 100% so it's pushing the footer out. you can try with `height: calc(100% - 20px);` on the #content where 20px is the height of the footer.

Comment: This does work. Is there a way to not have to set 20px in the height and have the height of the footer be dymanic?

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was after.